# Set-Cookie on header yet Cookie is not being set

Tags: angular, http, cookies, nestjs, setcookie

I have a NestJS Application server being hit from an Angular Webapp. My NestJS server is located at https://api.example.com while my Angular app is hosted at https://example.com

I sent the {withCredentials: true} option on my Angular HTTP Post to login, and the response comes with a Set-Cookie header as follows:

SessionId=XXXXXXXX; Path=/; HttpOnly=false; Secure; Max-Age=3600;

Since the Set-Cookie header is passed successfully from the server --> frontend, shouldn't it be set? I programmatically try to access the cookie in subsequent requests and it's always null.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly do you "_try to access the cookie in subsequent requests_"?

Comment: @Ivar I’m using the ngx-cookie-service library, this all worked fine when it was localhost.    https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: If your api is on `api.example.com` and your `Set-Cookie` header is set from there, your cookie will only be available on `api.example.com`, not on `example.com`. That is probably why you can't access it. But do you really need to access it? Sending an other request to `api.example.com` should include this cookie automatically.

Comment: There could be a couple of reasons why cookie is not attached to the request, I summed them up in this post. https://medium.com/swlh/7-keys-to-the-mystery-of-a-missing-cookie-fdf22b012f09?source=friends_link&sk=267ea4da1013e10f6934873fcfbff42b. .Also note that preflight OPTIONS request  is not sending credentials